# Vue.js bind the :value of a elment on a v-if condition

Tags: vue.js

Is it possible to bind the :value of a html element on v-if condition like:

```
<td v-if="isset == true" :value="value1" v-else :value="value2"></td>
```

So the v-if should only bind the :value not the whole element

---

I dont need this, this doesnt work for me:

```
<td v-if="isset == true" :value="value1"></td>

<td v-else :value="value2"></td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can just do this:

```
<td :value="isset == true ? value1 : value2"></td>
```

Or even better: use a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)